# let the User have an access to the Webserver internal network IP adress in ASP.NET/MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to build a website , allows a public user (a vistor from internet) to access a specific internal IP of the webserver internal network , for example :  I have a website built on a windows machine that belongs to an internal network. This network has a surveillance camera system on internal IP 129.168.0.100 . So i want after auth. that vistor to have access to that IP ...

If not possible. what other possibilities do i have to get this done ?

Thank you very much ....

Comment: You're looking for a proxy.  Beware of security issues.

Comment: This is no different than running an ftp server on your local machine and accessing it from the outside world. Basically, SLaks got a point where a proxy can guarantee by user, whereas you can just use your router and port forwarding to forward request to [PublicIP]:Port80 - [PrivateIP]:Port80, you can also change the ports on either end. Private IP addresses like 192.168.X.X are by definition private and can only be accessed by some port forwarding mechanism or proxy/vpn

Comment: As far as auth goes, since the reques is just passed through, your security camera interface must do the autentication

Comment: @SLaks:
thanks . but, still have no idea how to make the proxy in the page it self.!

Comment: @TimDavis:
thank you man , but i am here avoiding port forwarding in Router . I need to make it programmatically.